# Отсутствует перевод на странице "Скрыть сообщества"

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, локализация

Отсутствует перевод на странице "Скрыть сообщества":

> Профиль - Править - Скрыть сообщества

---

> Hiding a community means other users will not see it in your Communities list or Top Network Posts. It does not, however, mean your activity is private.

Там же еще и кнопки <kbd>Hide</kbd>, <kbd>Unhide</kbd> требуют перевода.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky по кнопкам тоже исправлено?

Comment: К сожалению, нет, из нет на Transifex. Сейчас попробую добавить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В transifex оказывается [имеется](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/74997506?q=hiding%20a%20community) ещё один (пока не утвержденный) вариант от @andreycha:

> `Если вы скрываете сообщество, то остальные пользователи не увидят его в списке Сообществ или Лучших сообщений сети. **При этом ваша активность в этом сообществе остается видимой**.`

[Выполнен перевод текста кнопок Hide/Unhide.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290184/339911)

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю следующий перевод (сомнительного качества):

> Скрытие сообщества означает, что другие пользователи не будут видеть его в списке ваших сообществ или лучших сообщений сети. Тем не менее, это не означает, что ваши действия будут скрыты от других пользователей.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю переписать все три абзаца вместе с подзаголовками:

> Какие сообщества не показывать в профиле?
>
> В профиле под вашим изображением есть два списка —
>   «Сообщества» и «Лучшие сообщения
>   в сети». По умолчанию в них попадают все
>   сообщества, к которым вы присоединяетесь.
>
> Если сообщество скрыть, то оно исчезнет из этих списков.
>   Но ваши действия в самом сообществе всё равно все увидят.
>
> **Показывать всем**
>   ...
>
> **Скрывать от других пользователей**
>   ...

Английский оригинал:

> Choose which communities will appear in the Communities and Top
>   Network Posts sections of your profile
>
> Hiding a community means other users will not see it in your
>   Communities list or Top Network Posts. It does not, however, mean your
>   activity is private.
>
> New sites that you join will be linked to your other communities by
>   default.
>
> **Visible Communities - others see these**
>   ...
>
> **Hidden Communities - others will not see these**
>   ...